# Virtual box linux routing

Tags: linux, networking, nat, virtualbox

Sorry for the basic question but I cant figure this one out. I want to set up a small network of linux servers for testing purposes.

So I have a host server running virtual box with the following interface:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Then a guest vm with the following networking set up:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:EA:15:4F  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:E3:E2:BC  
          inet addr:172.16.0.1  Bcast:172.16.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
```

And a second vm guest set up as follows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:15:CA:14  
          inet addr:172.16.0.2  Bcast:172.16.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe15:ca14/64 Scope:Link
```

I want to be able to route from vm 2 back to the host server. So I created a route telling vm 2 to send traffic for the `192.169.0.0` network via vm 1:

```
% route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     172.16.0.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
```

But I can not ping through to the `192.168.0.0` network from vm 2. Routing table on vm 1 is as follows:

```
% route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

the routing table on the host server (running virtual box) is :

```
% route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

so I guess my problem is that the host server knows nothing of my VM's `172.16.0.0/16` network and can't reply.

How can I fix this, will I have to use iptables and NATing?

Comment: Please format the post.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever done this with a windows host, and Linux Guests, but the principle should be the same.

Check the following link, specifically on Host-only networking

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

I didn't need to edit the routes at all with this method.

Another route you might want to explore is using Vagrant. http://www.vagrantup.com/
Its excellent for testing out different configurations & setting up new VMs really quickly.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively trying to configure VM1 as a router. You will need to:

1. VM1 - Turn on `net.ipv4.ip_forward` in `sysctl` - this may vary based on distribution
2. VM1 - Make sure iptables is allowing forwarding
3. Make sure VM1 has routes to both networks (which it should if directly attached)
4. Make sure your host has routes to 172 network via VM1